# How is Botan (the Japanese rice candy) made?

Tags: candy

I was wondering if anyone might know how they make Botan Rice Candy? I have searched the web but no leads.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! One of our biggest rules is that we don't allow recipe requests, so I edited your question in the hope that it will be enough to allow it to stay open. I looked too, and could not find anything about how to make Botan. I did read that it is similar to Mochi, and there is a lot online about that. Google search for Mochi, and see if that helps. I actually plan to try it myself soon!

Comment: Specifically, you might find this [Blog](http://notesonsugar.com/?p=165) on Mochi of interest.

Comment: @jolenealaska thanks for the tip! The blog  post was just what l was hoping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this one?[botan rice candy](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=botan%20candy&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE2sua-bTPAhUFupQKHdBhC1AQsAQIGw&biw=1054&bih=604).

If so, in Japan it is actually known as [Bontan Ame](http://kyotofoodie.com/bontan-ame/)  (meaning pomelo candy) as shown in this description.

Here is a [link](http://m-jun.up.n.seesaa.net/m-jun/image/20140326-02_s.jpg?d=a1) to how a similar milk version is made (I think you would use mandarin/pomelo (bontan) juice in there somewhere for what you want), but it is in Japanese...Perhaps the pictures will help but...sorry, I don't know if it's ok to translate this...but it says: milk 500ml, sweet glutinous rice 500g, sugar 500g, mizuame (maltose; could use corn syrup instead) 600g, potato starch 200g, and a tray 31cmx24cmx3.5cm. Briefly, it says to soak the rice for half a day, then drain, and blend with the milk for 2-3 mins. Transfer to a pot and simmer on medium heat for 20-30 mins. Add sugar in a few lots, mix until dissolved. Drop to low heat, add mizuame and stir/knead very well - the firmness of the final candy will depend on how long you do this. Dredge tray with a thick layer of potato starch then pour the mixture in. To harden, refrigerate when cool.

Comment: If you give the source, translating the recipe is absolutely fine. On the contrary, "link only" answers are discouraged, because links on the Internet have that notorious tendency to be not permanent ("link rot"), which would make the answer useless.